# Why can the anonymous type be changed if it is supposed to be immutable?

Tags: c#, linq

I thought I had a good understanding of the anonymous type, but this small code snippet has left me a little confused:

```
string[] arr = { "Agnes", "Allan", "Benny" };

var result = arr.Where(a => a.StartsWith("A")).Select(a => a);

// Why can I do the below, if arr is immutable?
result = arr.Where(a => a.EndsWith("n")).Select(a => a);
```

What I don't understand is why I am allowed to assign a second value to `result`. I mean isn't the idea of anonymous types being immutable, that they cannot be changed after they have got their initial value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First, there is no [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb397696.aspx) involved.**

---

This `string[] arr = { "Agnes", "Allan", "Benny" };` is an [array creation expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

`result` is `IEnumerable<string>` and in both LINQ statements you are just creating a query.

This is what is going on:

*array creation expression*

```
string[] arr = { "Agnes", "Allan", "Benny" };
```

*query arr and returns `IEnumerable<string>`*

```
var result = arr.Where(a => a.StartsWith("A")).Select(a => a);
```

*assigns results a new query on arr returning `IEnumerable<string>`*

```
result = arr.Where(a => a.EndsWith("n")).Select(a => a);
```

As far as, for understanding immutability, think of `String` also see this article: [Immutable types: understand their benefits and use them](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=immutable%20types%20jon%20skeet%20C%23)

Comment: @Habib: Thanks! Just to understand this, how should my LINQ statement look then, if it was supposed to return an anonymous type?

Comment: @brinch Anonymous types are difficult to be returned from methods, or to be passed to other methods. They are used to store "temporary data" "inside" a method. There is an horrible hack to return an anonymous type, or you can use `dynamic` (but in general you shouldn't return an anonymous object)

Comment: @Habib: Just for the record, I guess this would then make res anonymous:

var res = from n in names
               where n.StartsWith("N")
               select new { n };

Comment: @brinch, yes, that will return you `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` would be an anonymous type

Answer (score 3):

You have an anonymous type when you do something like:

```
var anon = new { X = 5, Y = 6 };
```

There are some pretty simple rules: you can't express the type of an anonymous type (so often you use `var`)... there must be a `new {`... You must give a name to the properties and a value `X = 5`.

What you are doing is creating an array of `string[]` using an array initializer. You are even writing it:

```
string[] arr = ...
```

And you aren't modifying anything... `result` is another variable, referencing an `IEnumerable<>` (a new object you are creating) and then referencing another `IEnumerable<>` At the end of your code you have 6 objects (a little more, but we will ignore some invisible objects):

- The array referenced by `arr` (and referenced by the two `IEnumerable<>`)
- The second `IEnumerable<>`, referenced by `result`, that has a reference to `arr`
- The first `IEnumerable<>`, not referenced by anyone (the GC will collect it before or later), that has a reference to `arr`
- 3x `string`, all referenced by `arr`. Note that `IEnumerable<>` are "lazy", so they don't contain any reference to any `string`

The `result` variable is assigned twice, to two different `IEnumerable<>`. It is nearly always legal to reassign variables (exception are `readonly` fields). it is clearly legal to do:

```
string foo = "Foo";
foo = "Bar";
```

Answer (score 2):

Another useful concept to understand is the difference between type, instance and variable.

Simplifying, type is like a blueprint, it describes what an instance of the type will look like:

```
class Car
{
   public int Doors {get; set;}
   public string EngineType { get; set;}
}
```

The code above describes type. You can make many instances of this type:

```
Car truck = new Car { Doors = 2, EngineType = "BigEckingEngine" };  
Car pickup = new Car { Doors = 5, Engine Type = "4 cylinder" };
```

etc...
Note how variables truck and pickup house your instances. But variables are just that, they can house any instance of their respective type, so while it does not make much sense you can do this:

```
Car tmp = truck;
truck = pickup;
pickup = tmp;
```

The instances themselves has not changed. But the variables now hold different instances.

The instances of this example `Car` class above are mutable. So you can do this:

```
pickup.Doors = 99;
```

Should the type be immutable, you would not be able to do that, but you are still can do variable assigning as in the example with the `tmp` variable freely, regardless of type being mutable or not, because such assignment do not change instances.

As noted, your example does not contain an anonymous type, but even if it did, it does not involve any kind of mutation you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ methods like `Where()` and `Select()` don't change the underlying array. It creates a new object. The created `result` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, LINQ just filters the array so if you will iterate over it later, you will just get values that match `Where` and `Select` but your `arr` object will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth expanding the other answers to show that a CONCRETE resolution of a LINQ query is not the same as a `IEnumerable<T>` and that neither have anything to do with anonymous type immutability.

If you created the following array of anonymous types:

```
var arr = new[] { new { Name = "Agnes"}, new { Name = "Allan" }, new { Name = "Benny" }};

arr.GetType().Dump();

var result = arr.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("A")).Select(a => a)
result = arr.Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith("n")).Select(a => a);

result.Dump();
```

in my case,

```
<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String][]
```

and

```
"Allan"
```

are respectively outputted, because result type is actually

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[
    <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String],
    <>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]
```

In addition, if I try to resolve the IEnumerable and then re-update the result:

```
var result = arr.Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("A")).Select(a => a).ToList();
result = arr.Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith("n")).Select(a => a).ToList();
```

I once again get an output of

```
"Allan"
```

However, in this case my result type has been reevaluated to

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]
```

since `ToList()` is creating a new collection.  I can technically add and remove to that collection at will since the collection itself is quite willing to be mutated.

Finally, that does not mean that the underlying anonymous type object is not immutable!

```
result.First ().Name = "fail";
```

Will fail, regardless of result being a list with the following error:

> Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it
>   is read only

***precisely*** because it is immutable.